# Recovery a property value from a proxy in another proxy in wso2 6.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I had to create a property in a proxy, and its working properly, but I have to use this value in another proxy inside the same project.

I've tried to use this:

```
<property expression="$ctx:property-name" name="property-name"/>
```

But didn't work. Someone knows if is possible to get this value? If possible, how to do?

Comment: Create a shared sequence that sets the property value and call it from both proxies.

Comment: I've tried this solution... but didn't worked, when a try recovery the property on another proxy a receive a null value.

Comment: You can't get a property from another proxy. What you can do is set then to the same value.

Comment: The value can either be a constant or something you read from the registry

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of this workarounds will help you.

- pass the value as parameter (e.g. set a http header, soap property) from one proxy to another if possible
- store you're value in a database (e.g. internal H2 database) and access it from the second proxy

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the class mediator option available in WSO2 ESB.

The property that needs to be referred from another proxy or service, can be passed to this custom mediator.

```
<class name="samples.mediators.SimpleClassMediator">
    <property name="variable1" value="10"/>
    <property name="variable2" value="5"/>
</class>
```

When we implement this custom class mediator by implementing the `Mediator` or the `AbstractMediator` interface, through `mediate(MessageContext synCtx)` method, we get the access to Synapse Message context (the properties in this object will be available to all mediators in the same service).

With `MessageContext` object, you can access other global context objects like `SynapseConfiguration`, `SynapseEnvironment` etc.,

So in the mediate method, you can access the `SynapseConfiguration` object and use the `setProperty(String key, String value)` method on it and pass your property that needs to be accessed by other services or APIs. Access this property by calling `getProperty()` on SynapseConfiguration object by writing a similar class mediator.

References:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Class+Mediator
http://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/config/SynapseConfiguration.html

Comment: Hi, sorry to post a question to an old answer. Doesn't the class mediator get instantiated as a new object every time a message arrives into the mediator. If so, how can it hold state from one proxy service to another?

Comment: Hi @PetteriPertola the class mediator will instantiate a single instance of the class. If request level synchronization is needed, the same has to be handled. Also this approach should be used based on the use case. Also my thought was to save the property at global context objects like SynapseConfiguration and not at the custom class mediator implementation.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. For my use case i can't save it in SynapseConfig because it's not global in the sense that it will be available across different proxy services.

The documentation about class mediators is not very good in this part in general. Thanks.